# Signalr working locally but not working on Server

Tags: .net, ubuntu, websocket, signalr

I Can use signalR on locally, but I can't use it on real server , I receive proxy error .
**Tools are :(nginx version 1.20 - ubuntu - .Netcore)**

Error Message on console :

*WebSocket failed to connect. The connection could not be found on the server, either the endpoint may not be a SignalR endpoint, the connection ID is not present on the server, or there is a proxy blocking WebSockets. If you have multiple servers check that sticky sessions are enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The problem is our nginx version is 1.2 but websocket(signalR) feature comes with version 1.3+* .**Now alternative awesome solution to this is  , using LongPolling instead of WebSockets**. Hope this can help whoever facing with this issue.